# Progression Bar for the File import

Tags: java

I have a import conditon like

```
if (analyze.equals("IMPORT")) 
    {
        datas=(Vector)session.getAttribute("data");

        // code which is working succesfully for the import

 }
```

My file will take around 30 secs to upload, in the meanwhile i need to add a progression bar, within this "Import" condition.

How can i do this ?

Tried with Jframe, but it need to extend Jframe class.

But already one servlet is extending my existing class.

Please provide the solution.

Comment: This looks like Java, not JavaScript. The two are very different languages, please remove the JavaScript tag.

Answer (score 0):

To show progress using Swing you can use component JProgressBar

```
JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(<min value> , <max value>);    
jb.setBounds(x,y,width,height);        
add(jb);
```

Use this method to set value of a bar

```
progressBar.setValue(int value);
```

Use this method to toggle displaying progress in text on the bar

```
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
```

Comment: I have a "progression.jsp" file, It shows progression percentage.








the data which comes from --> store =(Vector)session.getAttribute("data");








I want to forward "store" to my "progression.jsp"